# To show the user._id when a button is clicked in vue3 I create printname function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
              <td class="one-third column" v-for="user in users" :key="user._id">
                  <div>   
                   <v-btn  @click="printName"   height="50" size="large"  color="purple" >
                      {{ user.it_name.slice(0, 10) }}
                  </v-btn>  
              </div>
              </td>

<script  setup>
function printName(user) {
    console.log(user._id.value);
  }
</script>
```

the result is  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value'
How to print in console user._id or user.it_name    Thank

Comment: console.log(user._id.value) change to console.log(user._id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass that user to the method.

```
<v-btn  @click="printName(user)" height="50" size="large"  color="purple" >
    {{ user.it_name.slice(0, 10) }}
</v-btn>
```

And then in your method you can print any of its properties:

```
function printName(user) {
    console.log(user._id);
}
```